# Appropriate length of chromosome in Genetic Algorithms

Tags: optimization

In order to find the appropriate length of chromosomes in GA programming, the author of [this book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540606765) states:

> Suppose six decimal places for the variables' values is desirable.
>   It is clear that to achieve such precision each domain *`Di = [ai,bi]`* should be
>   cut into *`(bi - ai) * 10^6`* equal size ranges. Let us denote by *`mi`* the
>   smallest integer such that *`(bi - ai) * 10^6 <= 2^mi - 1`*. Then, a
>   representation having each variable *`xi`* coded as a binary string of
>   length *`mi`* clearly satisfies the precision requirement. Additionally, the following formula interprets each such string:
>
> `xi = ai + decimal(1001...001) * (bi - ai)/(2^mi - 1)`
>
> where `decimal(string)` represents the decimal value of that
>   binary string.

So here is my question: Why is the author using `(bi - ai)/(2^mi - 1)`? Why not `(bi - ai)/(2^mi)`? What is that `-1` for?

I searched it and I thought it might have something to do with the Mersenne Prime numbers because of the formulation!! I also checked out the [Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_(genetic_algorithms)#Length) as I thought it might be related to that, but these all seem completely unrelated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author uses (2^mi - 1) because it is necessary for the encoding to have values representing BOTH ai and bi (note: the interval is closed, i.e contains both endpoints).  The author is using mi bits to represent 2^mi values, so the interval [ai, bi] is being divided to produce 2^mi representable points - and this necessarily divides up the interval into (2^mi - 1) sub-intervals.  That's a general property, by the way - if you mark N points inside a closed interval, you produce N+1 sub-intervals [to see this, note that each point -except the last- starts one of the sub-intervals].  Here N is (2^mi - 1).